# How to listen user while playing chunk of audio with qt and simpleaudio

Tags: python, audio, pyqt, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I am trying to play an audio signal with simpleaudio inside a GUI application where the user should react to the content of the chunk played and push a button. At the moment the users push the button I would like to change to the next track. This is all done using the slot and signals from qt in Python 3.x using pytq5. Even when my GUI does not freeze I do not understand why I cannot read the button action during (between) the chunks of audio that are been played, instead all actions are readed after all tracks finish.

My code looks like this:
Module to handle the tracks and chunks

```
import simpleaudio as sa
import numpy as np

class MusicReactor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.timeProTone = ...
        self.deltaT = ...
        self.maxVolSkal = ...
        self.minVolSkal = ...
        self.frequencySample = ...
        self.currentTestedEar = ...
        
        
    def test_function(self, frequency):
        # array of time values
        times = np.arange(0, self.timeProTone, self.deltaT)
        # generator to create a callable object with new volume each time
        for time in times:
            # get the volume and set the volume to the starting sequence
            currentVolume = (self.maxVolSkal-self.minVolSkal)/self.timeProTone * time + self.minVolSkal
            self.setVolumeScalar(currentVolume)
            # create chunk the tone as a numpy array
            audio = createTone(frequency, self.deltaT, self.frequencySample, self.currentTestedEar)
            yield audio, currentVolume


def createTone(frequency, duration, frequencySampled, currentTestedEar = TestEar.Both):

    # Generate array with seconds*sample_rate steps, ranging between 0 and seconds
    tt = np.linspace((0, 0), (duration, duration), int(duration * frequencySampled), False)

    #populate the other ear with zeros
    if currentTestedEar is not TestEar.Both:
        tt[:, 1-currentTestedEar.value] = 0 # This strategy works only if the note creation i a sinusoidal : sin(0) = 0

    # Generate a 440 Hz sine wave
    note = np.sin(frequency * tt * 2 * np.pi)

    # normalize to 16-bit range
    note *= 32767 / np.max(np.abs(note))

    # Ensure that highest value is in 16-bit range
    audio = note * (2 ** 15 - 1) / np.max(np.abs(note))

    # Convert to 16-bit data
    audio = audio.astype(np.int16)
    return audio

def playTone(audio, frequencySample, num_channels=1, bytes_per_sample=2):
    # Start playback
    play_obj = sa.play_buffer(audio, num_channels, bytes_per_sample, frequencySample)
    # Wait for playback to finish before exiting
    play_obj.wait_done()

def generateRndFreq(minF,maxF):
    freq = np.random.uniform(low=minF, high=maxF)
    return freq
```

Now the GUI class and its corresponding worker class

```
class HearingTest_ui(QWidget):
    # Send info through signals to subthreads
    sig_int_sender = pyqtSignal(int)
    hearingObjSender = pyqtSignal( Hearing.HearingTest)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        uic.loadUi("testForm.ui", self)

        
        self.Both_rB.toggled.connect(self.onTogle_earTested)
        self.Links_rB.toggled.connect(self.onTogle_earTested)
        self.Recht_rB.toggled.connect(self.onTogle_earTested)


        # Method 2 Test
        self.ML_startButton.clicked.connect(self.runMethod2Test)
        self.setMaxMLProgressBar()
        self.ml_nTests = self.ML_spinBox.value()
        self.ML_spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.setNTests)
        self.ML_spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.setMaxMLProgressBar)

        # Hearing Test Object
        self.HT = Hearing.MusicReactor()


    def runMethod2Test(self):
        # Preprocessing
        self.HT.choose_ear(self.testedEarTuple) # reads a tpogle to assign a channel for the chunk of music
        # thread and worker configuration
        # Step 2: Create a QThread object
        self.ml_thread = QThread(parent=self)
        # Step 3: Create a worker object
        self.ml_worker = ML_Worker(self.ml_nTests)
        # Step 4: Move worker to the thread
        self.ml_worker.moveToThread(self.ml_thread)
        # Step 5: Connect signals and slots
        #self.ml_thread.started.connect(partial(self.ml_worker.actualLongTaskFromHearingTest, self.HT))
        self.hearingObjSender.connect(self.ml_worker.actualLongTaskFromHearingTest)
        self.ml_worker.progress.connect(self.updateProgressbar)
        self.ML_spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.ml_worker.set_maxTests)
        self.sig_int_sender.connect(self.ml_worker.set_maxTests)
        self.ML_yesButton.clicked.connect(self.ml_worker.change_Flag)
        self.ml_worker.request_playchunk.connect(self.ml_worker.sendAudio2queue)
        self.ml_worker.finished.connect(self.ml_thread.quit)
        self.ml_worker.finished.connect(self.ml_worker.deleteLater)
        self.ml_thread.finished.connect(self.ml_thread.deleteLater)
        # Final resets
        self.ml_worker.changeButtonStatus.connect(self.ML_startButton.setEnabled)

        # start thread
        print("clicked runMethodOfLimits")
        self.ml_thread.start()

        self.hearingObjSender.emit(self.HT)



class ML_Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)
    retrieve = pyqtSignal()
    changeButtonStatus = pyqtSignal(bool)
    request_playchunk = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray, int, Hearing.MusicReactor)

    def __init__(self,nTest):
        super().__init__()
        self.__abort = False
        self.nTests = nTest
        self.MoLFlag = False

    def abort(self):
        self.__abort = True

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def set_maxTests(self, val):
        print(type(val))
        logging.info(f"set_maxTests.... {val}")
        self.nTests = val

    @pyqtSlot()
    def change_Flag(self):
        print("clicked")
        self.MoLFlag = True

    # def of long runnning task
    @pyqtSlot(Hearing.MusicReactor)
    def actualLongTaskFromHearingTest(self, HTObj):
        self.changeButtonStatus.emit(False)
        self.progress.emit(0)
        self.retrieve.emit()
        print(self.nTests)
        start = 0
        for i in range(self.nTests):
            self.MoLFlag = False
            j = i + 1
            print("start", i)
            # create the frequency for the test
            chunk_freq = Hearing.generateRndFreq(0, 10000)
            #create chunks as generator
            for chunk, volume in HTObj.test_function(chunk_freq):
                # play chunk of the audio
                self.request_playchunk.emit(chunk, 2, HTObj) # this is my current method, by using the signals and slots
                # Hearing.playTone(chunk, HTObj.frequencySample, num_channels=2)^# previously I tried something like this, which resulted in the same behavior
                print(volume)

                if self.MoLFlag:
                    print(self.MoLFlag)
                    break

        self.progress.emit(j)
        self.changeButtonStatus.emit(True)
        self.finished.emit()

    @pyqtSlot(np.ndarray, int, Hearing.MusicReactor)
    def sendAudio2queue(self, chunk, channels, HTObj):
        Hearing.playTone(chunk, HTObj.frequencySample, num_channels=channels)
```

If somebody could take I look I would be very gratefull. I would really like to understand why this is happening. I believe it has something to do with the thread queue, probably I would need to open a new thread which is in charge of the music while the otherone takes care of the GUI reactions, but still I do not understand why it does not break the loop (with the generator) when I click the "ML_yesButton".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to use threads in this case. The [`wait_done()`](https://simpleaudio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simpleaudio.html#simpleaudio.PlayObject.wait_done) method blocks the thread where it is executed so that the application does not terminate before finishing playing the audio.

In this case a QTimer can be used to check if the audio finished playing.

```py
import simpleaudio as sa
import numpy as np

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class AudioManager(QObject):
    started = pyqtSignal()
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._play_obj = None

        self._timer = QTimer(interval=10)
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self._handle_timeout)

    def start(self, audio_data, num_channels, bytes_per_sample, sample_rate):
        self._play_obj = sa.play_buffer(
            audio_data, num_channels, bytes_per_sample, sample_rate
        )
        self._timer.start()
        self.started.emit()

    def stop(self):
        if self._play_obj is None:
            return
        self._play_obj.stop()
        self._play_obj = None
        self.finished.emit()

    def _handle_timeout(self):
        if self._play_obj is None:
            return
        if not self.running():
            self.stop()

    def running(self):
        return self._play_obj.is_playing()


def create_tone(duration, fs, f):
    tt = np.linspace((0, 0), (duration, duration), int(duration * fs), False)
    note = np.sin(f * tt * 2 * np.pi)
    note *= 32767 / np.max(np.abs(note))
    audio = note * (2 ** 15 - 1) / np.max(np.abs(note))
    audio = audio.astype(np.int16)
    return audio


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.audio_manager = AudioManager()
        self.audio_manager.started.connect(self.handle_started)
        self.audio_manager.finished.connect(self.handle_finished)

        self.button = QPushButton("Start", checkable=True)
        self.button.toggled.connect(self.handle_toggled)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.button, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

    def handle_toggled(self, state):
        if state:
            frequency = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10000)
            tone = create_tone(60, 1000, frequency)
            self.audio_manager.start(tone, 1, 2, 16000)

        else:
            self.audio_manager.stop()
            self.button.setText("Start")

    def handle_started(self):
        self.button.setChecked(True)
        self.button.setText("Stop")

    def handle_finished(self):
        self.button.setChecked(False)
        self.button.setText("Start")


def main():
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = Widget()
    widget.resize(640, 480)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!

This works nicely as standalone, I will try to implement this in my code, besides I believe you solved another problem I had about continuosly play the whole track and only change its volume as the time goes. I wonder what else I can do now.

Comment: @CesarGarcia I do not implement in your code since there are many things that are confusing (a lot of code that is not visible). If you want more help then you must provide a [mre]. Also read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: I completely understand what you mean, but I think it was a job well done. I like to do the implementation and learn what is missing

Comment: I will not forget, let me implement it and try out.

Comment: Sorry that it took so long.